# Store array inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

I have a store with office and inside i have the array people. So it look like this/l

```
const office = (state = INITIAL_OFFICE, action) => {
    switch(action.type){

        case 'ADD_OFFICE':
            const office = action.item;
            office.people = [];
            return {
                ...state,
                offices: [...state.offices, office],
            }

            case 'ADD_PEOPLE_TO_DEVICE':
            const { office_id, id, name } = action.item
            const offices = [...state.offices];
            offices[office_id+1].people.push({ name })

            return {
                ...state,
                offices
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I created api which return json witrh 3 field - office_id, id of person and name of person. I want to add all people to array inside suitable office object. At this moment it display only 1 person in the office (I have many-to-many relationship) and Firefox (Chrome not) display my an error

> offices[(office_id + 1)] is undefined

If I update manually key of protocols, for example protocols[2], all elements display with suitable office. How can I add all people to suitable office?

Comment: in `ADD_OFFICE`  you are returning `office` but in `ADD_PEOPLE_TO_DEVICE` you are returning `offices` so I think that is the problem here.

Comment: I make a mistake until write the post but it doen't wrong code, I updated the post.

Comment: Looks like an "off by one (or more)" error. It seems that `office_id+1` is larger than `offices.length-1` . How is the value of `office_id` set?

Comment: Is office id. Is not langer.

Comment: You do not want to use `.push()` inside a redux reducer.  `const offices = [...state.offices]` creates a shallow copy.  You will still be mutating the underlying object for the `office`.

Comment: This `offices[office_id+1]` is very strange.  You might be using the array index as the `office_id`, but why would you add `1`?

It is honestly much easier to deal with an `object` which is keyed by `office_id` than to deal with an `array` in a redux reducer.